# Как сделать формирование хлебных крошек, в зависимости от того, как юзер попал в товар?

Tags: prestashop

Здравствуйте. Суть следующая - товар, входит в несколько категорий и при попадании в него, не из главной категории, иерархия крошек не совпадает с тем, как пользователь пришел в этот товар.

Как сделать так, чтобы крошки формировались в зависимости от того, из какой категории пришел пользователь?

За ранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В массиве $_SERVER есть ключ HTTP_REFERER, в нем хранится предыдущий адрес, с которого перешел пользователь. Но работает именно при переходе, а не открытии страницы сразу. Можно проверять - если ключ не пустой - подставлять в крошки его, а если пуст - то по умолчанию